# UICollectionViewLayout with horizontal and vertical pagination

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, pagination, collectionview

as title says I need a uicollectionview which is able to paginate in both directions as shown in the image.

[image: Layout]

Each square is the ios screen and the arrows indicate where pagination is allowed. UICollectionViewFlowLayout allows only scrolling and pagination in one direction. THe middle screens are where the main information is presented and swiping should only be allowed horizontally for those, while the others display extra information. Each column represent a specific item from a list, the dots indicate that my collection is dynamic based on the length of the list. In this example there are only 3 items displayed.

How would i go about solving this problem? Prefereably solutions in swift

Comment: Use a `UITableView` with custom cell. Custom cell contains a `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Could I do the same with a uicollectionview inside a uicollectionview cell?

Comment: It will be a bit clumsy with a uicollectionview inside a uicollectionview cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building it with a UICollectionView inside another UICollectionView